# Excel Dynamic Arrays - possible bug?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I have 5 numbers entered in cells B1:F1.  If I write the following formula:

```
= MIN( OFFSET( A1, 0, {1,3,5} ) )
```

then it correctly returns the smallest of the numbers in cells B1, D1, F1.
However, if I get rid of the MIN() and make the formula:

```
= OFFSET( A1, 0, {1,3,5} )
```

I would expect it to return the 3 numbers as a dynamic array.  It *does* return a dynamic array sized correctly, but in each of the 3 cells it gives me #VALUE!.
That would seem to be a bug - and I know dynamic arrays are relatively new - but would anybody have any thoughts to the contrary?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably better to just use `INDEX` as it's not volatile.

```
=INDEX(B1:F1,,{1,3,5})
```

**EDIT**:

For a more general version of this, consider:

```
=INDEX(1:1,,{2, 4, 6})
```

or

```
=INDEX(1:1,,{1, 3, 5}+1)
```

Comment: Good answer.  A more general soultion: `=INDEX(1:1,,{2, 4, 6})` or `=INDEX(1:1,,{1, 3, 5}+1)`

Comment: @chrisneilsen - yep, that's good detail, will add to the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind!
It now works, but I didn't change anything.  It must be caused somehow by the fact that OFFSET is a volatile function...